# Spring mongodb very slow mapping between database and java objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

After upgrading Spring Boot and the mongo driver, I have noticed that the mongo queries are pretty fast, but when MongoTemplate internally maps the list of mongo Documents to my Java objects, it takes about 5 seconds for just 1000 objects. This was considerably faster before, when using Spring Boot 2.1.7 and an earlier version of mongo-driver.

My current setup is:

spring-boot:3.2.7, spring-data-mongodb:3.0.4 and mongodb-driver-sync:4.1.1.